# Accessing other partition from the command-line immediately on startup

Tags: command-line, mount, startup

My other hard drive partition (i.e., the Windows partition) is located in `/media/OS`.
However, I don't seem to be able to access it from the command line when my
machine starts up in Ubuntu.
I have to first open Nautilus and then click on the drive.
Only then can I access the drive from the command line.

- What is a simple way to ensure that the partition is always accessible from the command-line?

I thought perhaps there might be some simple command that I could add to the list of "startup applications".

Answer (score 4):

This is because your Windows partition is not mounted automatically when you started your Ubuntu. It is only mounted when you clicked on that drive in Nautilus. Trying this guide -> [AutomaticallyMountPartitions | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) to mount your Windows partition during startup.

Answer (score 1):

From commandline you can do

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdx1 /media/OS
```

instead of going to nautilus. Replace /dev/sdx1 with your the windows partition.

Easy setup of auto mounting NTFS partitions taken from [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions):

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
sudo ./ntfs-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/fstab. If you not sure What to put there, mount it first in nautilus, and see output of `mount` command.